# Image change pause/play javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript:

```
window.onload = intializePlayer;
function vidplay() {
    var video = document.getElementById("music");
    var button = document.getElementById("play");
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
        button.style.background = "url(/resources/play.png)";
    } else {
        video.pause();
        button.style.background = "url(/resources/pause.png)";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
button#play{
    background:url(../resources/pause.png);
    border:none;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="play" onclick="vidplay()"></button>
```

The image doesn't seem to want to change when I click it. How can I get the image to change `onClick`?

Comment: You've noticed the missing parenthesis, right ?

Comment: @user3605738 Did you debug the javascript code? What are the errors you get?

Comment: Fixed. Thank you, totally missed it.

Comment: I tried to edit but it requires a small, but crucial change, too small to be accepted.  You need a blank line after `HTML:' so the HTML code is recognized as a code block.   Currently it's not visible in your question.  Also you still have a couple missing close parentheses on your background settings.

Comment: This is a minor point, but I'd recommend putting the background images in a css class style and applying the class in the javascript.

Comment: I assume that closing the parenthesis did not fix the original problem?  I.e. was the original missing parenthesis?  If it's still not working, is it feasible provide the code for initializePlayer to make a runnable test case?